# Will water boil from top-down radiant heating?

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation

I've had a question about the nature of "boiling" for a while. When we observe water boiling, we are actually see several things happen. First, water vaporizes at spot on the bottom of our pot. Then the bubble of vaporized water rises to the top water surface.

I was wondering, if we instead apply heat to the top surface of the body of water, say though radiant heating, would we see the water "boil" as it does in a stove-top pan? Or would the water calmly vaporize from the top surface?

Comment: Thought experiment: what happens when the sun shines on the ocean or on a lake? Where is the water hottest?

Comment: @Transistor As far as I know, water is hottest at the surface. In addition, cold water sinks (unless it's ice.) Water is constantly evaporating off the surface. Is this the same as vaporization? If so, does the water reach 100 C?? That doesn't seem reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

It is practically difficult to get water to boil without what is known as nucleation sites.  Tiny imperfections in the heated wall provide increased heat transfer surfaces.  Pyrex containers in a microwave present an environment without such sites and the water can become superheated - above the normal boiling point, which can become dangerous - you can end up with a large steam bubble that ejects hot water all over you.

But of course with a large enough source of radiated heat we can boil water.  I think the primary issue with these systems is the on-off cycle that occurs daily.

Comment: What if you continue heating water in that perfect pyrex bowl with zero nucleation sites? What would eventually happen?

Comment: it does eventully boil, just violently and all at once

Comment: surprisingly, i had that happen with a cup of coffee ... took the cup out of the microwave oven, placed it on the counter and added a small amount of sugar ... 1/2 of the coffee was on the counter instantly